# Parallax scrolling effect not working on github pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, skrollr, parallax.js

I have been working on a simple parallax scrolling web page that works well on my local machine but did not take effect when I uploaded to github pages. I am using scrollr.js (javascript library for the parallax effect). Although I have checked the file directive  but all seems to be good. I need your candid advise/ solution as regards this. Thanks

Please check the [webpage](http://moilogic.github.io). Also you can see the files on github [here](http://github.com/moilogic/moilogic.github.io). Once again thank you as you contribute.

Comment: Have you looked for JavaScript Errors with open development tools in your browser while reloading the page?

Comment: Have a simple look at the console sometimes... Your paths to external .js files all are 404. [Printscreen](http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc370/Bes7weB/temp_zpshupmbdaz.jpg)

Comment: @edi. Thanks for your contribution. It really help.

Comment: @Louys. Thanks for your contribution. It really help.